# HP suggests for virtualization mode in BIOS to be turned off if it is not needed. Why?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bios, virtualization

Does it mean it's a performance gain or is it buggy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because theoretically it could be exploited by a virus to virtualize your entire OS and thus, be undetectable to your antivirus software.  Hence, if you are not using it, it's a good idea to leave it disabled.

Comment: Really? That seems doubtful.

Comment: Never mind. Apparently this is a thing. http://www.theta44.org/software/HVM_Rootkits_ddz_bh-usa-06.pdf